# i have issue Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment'

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, augmented-reality

**My Main Activity Class Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArFragment arFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {

            Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
            ModelRenderable.builder()
                    .setSource(this, Uri.parse("TocoToucan.sfb"))
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addModelToScene(anchor,modelRenderable));
        });    
    }

    private void addModelToScene(Anchor anchor, ModelRenderable modelRenderable){

        AnchorNode node = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        transformableNode.setParent(node);
        transformableNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);

        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(node);
        transformableNode.select();
    }
}
```

this is my layout

```
 <fragment
       android:id="@+id/arFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"/>
```

but I get a compile error:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment'

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the wrong type of `arFragment` variable. Ensure that the type of `arFragment` variable is `com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment` and the `SuppressWarnings` annotations are added.

So, the arFragment declaration will be like this,

```
private com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment arFragment;
```

or

you can import the `arFragment` class reference first then directly access the class to create a reference.

```
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArFragment arFragment;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
    }
}
```